# range of x³ to y³?

Tags: python-2.7, list, range

How would I generate a *list* of all cubes of (or squares, or square roots, etc) x to y?

How can a range be created as the result of function applied to all values x to y?

I attempted to create a list but hit problems when trying to cube a non-integer value, as well as possibly other issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cube each item in a list individually, rather than the whole list.

```
numbers=[1,2,3,4,5]
cubes=[]
for x in numbers:
    cubes.append(x**3)
```

This returns:

```
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125]
```

You can use `range` to generate this list:

```
for x in range(1, 6):
    cubes.append(x**3)
```

And simplify this as a list comprehension:

```
cubes=[x**3 for x in range(start, end)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function do do what you want. So if you want the squares of the numbers from `start` to `end`(excluded) you can do

```
result = map(lambda x: x * x, range(start, end))
```

You can also replace the `x * x` with any other function call as well. In general you could put the operation (cube, root) in a different function and call that in the `map`:

```
def operation(x):
    return x * x * x

result = map(lambda x: operation(x), range(start, end))
```

So say `start = 1` and `end = 4` then `result` will be

```
[1, 8, 27]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Probably just didn't use correct search terminology.